# $\int \sqrt{x} 2^{-\sqrt{x}}dx$. How to begin?

Tags: integration

Let's take:
$$\int \sqrt{x} 2^{-\sqrt{x}}dx$$
I don't know how to begin, I am asking for advice.

Comment: Try doing U-Substitution.

Comment: I tried. Give me a bit more advice.

Comment: If you tried, what did you end up with?

Comment: To be honest, I tried some simple substitution but none of them doesn't work.

Comment: What do you end up with when $u^2 = x$?

Comment: Try more? :) The $2$ is just confusing here, you could try first with $e$ instead of $2$, find the technique, and then do a similar technique with $2$ instead of $e$.

Comment: Also note that $2^{-u} = e^{-u\ln 2}$ to make integration easier.

Comment: set $t=-\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can't you come up with a way of the buffalo style solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since $x$ appears under the radical, you can assume $x\geq0$. Then it is valid to write $x=t^2$, so that also $dx=d(t^2)=2t\;dt$. I think you should be able to take it from here, using integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$u = \sqrt{x} \Rightarrow du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} dx \Rightarrow 2u\  du = dx$$

Use integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Substitute $x = u^2$ (the most straight-forward thing to do in face of square roots) and obtain $\frac\partial{\partial u} x = 2 u$ so
$$\int \sqrt x 2^{-\sqrt x} \,dx = \int 2u^2 2^{-u} \, du$$
Now use partial integration and you're done.

Comment: help me with this partial, please.

Comment: @user180834 Notice that $\frac\partial{\partial u} 2^{-u} = -\ln2\ 2^{-u}$. You'll want to derive the polynomial part twice ($u^2$, then $2u$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $x = u^2$. Then $dx = 2udu$ and your integral can be rewritten as $$\int \sqrt{x} 2^{-\sqrt{x}}dx = \int u2^{-u}(2udu) \\ =2\int u^22^{-u}du$$ Now do integration by parts, and substitute back to get an answer in terms of $x$ after integrating.